# SCM missing reference

Tags: package, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

How can I find the package necessary to reference in my model por a returned type like

smmActivityPurpose

Thank you

I compare the packages referenced in the original form, but when I create a new one and use the same data, get the following error:

edit method 'psAeditActivityPurpose' defined on 'ProdTable', referenced in data source 'ProdTable' of form 'NewForm', returns type 'smmActivityPurpose', which is not recognized. Are you missing a module reference?   TestForm (USR) [Cambrica]   K:\AosService\PackagesLocalDirectory\bin\XppSource\Cambrica\AxForm_NewForm.xpp  0

Answer (score 0):

The missing package reference relates to the type `smmActivityPurpose`.

First identify the package by searching its name in VS, then update the package refence.

It is all explained [here](https://dynamics365musings.com/update-reference-packages-in-d365/).